# Docker Daemon is crashing and the docker services are not really up lately

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-machine, swarm

**Docker daemon got crashed after short span of time. Lately Docker services of stacks doesn't get properly up and resulted in app crash which only got fixed when i removed all the stacks and redeployed them.**

*I'm running my whole Android app and Other APIs on docker swarm cluster.*

*I have my machine running on Google Cloud platform with around 75 CPUs and 250G memory which is more than enough for all the services I'm running on my machine. I have haproxy in frontend which does reverse proxy, backend as python flask api with 5 replicas, Database connectivity through pgbouncer. Else Logspout, datadog, portainer, redis, etc.   *

*I couldn't understand that even if i have enough resources, proper setup system with enough max_pids still the daemon crashed.*

Generally Necessary:
- cgroup hierarchy: properly mounted [/sys/fs/cgroup]

- apparmor: enabled and tools installed
- CONFIG_NAMESPACES: enabled
- CONFIG_NET_NS: enabled
- CONFIG_PID_NS: enabled
- CONFIG_IPC_NS: enabled
- CONFIG_UTS_NS: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUPS: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_DEVICE: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_FREEZER: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_SCHED: enabled
- CONFIG_CPUSETS: enabled
- CONFIG_MEMCG: enabled
- CONFIG_KEYS: enabled
- CONFIG_VETH: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_BRIDGE: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_BRIDGE_NETFILTER: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_NF_NAT_IPV4: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_IP_NF_FILTER: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_MASQUERADE: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_ADDRTYPE: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNTRACK: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_IPVS: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_IP_NF_NAT: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_NF_NAT: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_NF_NAT_NEEDED: enabled
- CONFIG_POSIX_MQUEUE: enabled

Optional Features:

- CONFIG_USER_NS: enabled
- CONFIG_SECCOMP: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_PIDS: enabled
- CONFIG_MEMCG_SWAP: enabled
- CONFIG_MEMCG_SWAP_ENABLED: missing

  (cgroup swap accounting is currently enabled)
- CONFIG_LEGACY_VSYSCALL_EMULATE: enabled
- CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP: enabled
- CONFIG_BLK_DEV_THROTTLING: enabled
- CONFIG_IOSCHED_CFQ: enabled
- CONFIG_CFQ_GROUP_IOSCHED: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_PERF: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_HUGETLB: enabled
- CONFIG_NET_CLS_CGROUP: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_CGROUP_NET_PRIO: enabled
- CONFIG_CFS_BANDWIDTH: enabled
- CONFIG_FAIR_GROUP_SCHED: enabled
- CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED: missing
- CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_REDIRECT: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_IP_VS: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_IP_VS_NFCT: enabled
- CONFIG_IP_VS_PROTO_TCP: enabled
- CONFIG_IP_VS_PROTO_UDP: enabled
- CONFIG_IP_VS_RR: enabled (as module)
- CONFIG_EXT4_FS: enabled
- CONFIG_EXT4_FS_POSIX_ACL: enabled
- CONFIG_EXT4_FS_SECURITY: enabled
- Network Drivers:

  - "overlay":
  - CONFIG_VXLAN: enabled (as module)
  - CONFIG_BRIDGE_VLAN_FILTERING: enabled

    Optional (for encrypted networks):

    - CONFIG_CRYPTO: enabled
    - CONFIG_CRYPTO_AEAD: enabled
    - CONFIG_CRYPTO_GCM: enabled
    - CONFIG_CRYPTO_SEQIV: enabled
    - CONFIG_CRYPTO_GHASH: enabled
    - CONFIG_XFRM: enabled
    - CONFIG_XFRM_USER: enabled (as module)
    - CONFIG_XFRM_ALGO: enabled (as module)
    - CONFIG_INET_ESP: enabled (as module)
    - CONFIG_INET_XFRM_MODE_TRANSPORT: enabled (as module)
  - "ipvlan":
  - CONFIG_IPVLAN: enabled (as module)
  - "macvlan":
  - CONFIG_MACVLAN: enabled (as module)
  - CONFIG_DUMMY: enabled (as module)
  - "ftp,tftp client in container":
  - CONFIG_NF_NAT_FTP: enabled (as module)
  - CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_FTP: enabled (as module)
  - CONFIG_NF_NAT_TFTP: enabled (as module)
  - CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_TFTP: enabled (as module)
- Storage Drivers:

  - "aufs":
  - CONFIG_AUFS_FS: enabled (as module)
  - "btrfs":
  - CONFIG_BTRFS_FS: enabled (as module)
  - CONFIG_BTRFS_FS_POSIX_ACL: enabled
  - "devicemapper":
  - CONFIG_BLK_DEV_DM: enabled
  - CONFIG_DM_THIN_PROVISIONING: enabled (as module)
  - "overlay":
  - CONFIG_OVERLAY_FS: enabled (as module)
  - "zfs":
  - /dev/zfs: missing
  - zfs command: missing
  - zpool command: missing

Limits:

- /proc/sys/kernel/keys/root_maxkeys: 1000000

**NEED HELP ON UNDERSTANDING THE ISSUE HERE.**

**RESULT OF `docker info` here.**

Containers: 170

Running: 167

Paused: 0

Stopped: 3

Images: 144

Server Version: 18.09.7

Storage Driver: overlay2

Backing Filesystem: extfs

Supports d_type: true

Native Overlay Diff: true

Logging Driver: json-file

Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs

Plugins:

Volume: local

Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay

Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog

Swarm: active

NodeID: uqkfe247qfql50b1bft3r205b

Is Manager: true

ClusterID: fe79jmqus0l6zsa7kl41cbqa9

Managers: 1

Nodes: 2

Default Address Pool: 10.0.0.0/8

SubnetSize: 24

Orchestration:

Task History Retention Limit: 5

Raft:

Snapshot Interval: 10000

Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0

Heartbeat Tick: 1

Election Tick: 10

Dispatcher:

Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds

CA Configuration:

Expiry Duration: 3 months

Force Rotate: 0

Autolock Managers: false

Root Rotation In Progress: false

Node Address: 10.160.0.30

Manager Addresses:
  10.160.0.30:2377

Runtimes: runc

Default Runtime: runc

Init Binary: docker-init

containerd version:

runc version: N/A

init version: v0.18.0 (expected: fec3683b971d9c3ef73f284f176672c44b448662)

Security Options:

apparmor

seccomp

Profile: default

Kernel Version: 4.15.0-1040-gcp

Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

OSType: linux

Architecture: x86_64

CPUs: 76

Total Memory: 246GiB

Name: rc-manager-instance

ID: 2PEM:4AF6:47RA:EMDM:CIMD:H4OC:5MNG:SXNI:ERFB:ML5G:O3YI:6VWA

Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker

Debug Mode (client): false

Debug Mode (server): false

Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/

Labels:

Experimental: false

Insecure Registries:

10.160.0.30:7000

127.0.0.0/8

Live Restore Enabled: false

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please stop posting in ALL CAPS. It's widely regarded (not just here - generally on the web) as shouting and will make it less likely that folks will want to help you. Additionally, given that your screenshot is just text, it would be better to include that text in the question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have a look at [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).